# String or binary data would be truncated exception when inserting data

Tags: c#, sql

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error:

```
 An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in  
                       System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.
```

My code is:

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(EmpID) FROM EmpInfo";
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rdr.Close();
            //    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EmpInfo(EmpYear,EmpStatus,LName,FName,JobTitle,EmpPay,EmpDoB,EmpSex,EmpAddr,EmpCity,EmpState,EmpZIP,EmpCountry,EmpEAddr,EmpTelNo,EmpMobileNo) values('" + EmpYear + "', 'Active', '" + regLname_text.Text + "', '" + regFname_text.Text + "', 'NULL', '" + PayType_cb.SelectedItem.ToString() + "', '" + regDob_dtp.Value.Date + "', '" + gender + "', '" + regAddr_text.Text + "', '" + regCity_text.Text + "', '" + regState_text.Text + "', '" + regZip_text.Text + "', '" + regCountry_text.Text + "', '" + regEmail_text + "', '" + regTel_text.Text + "', '" + regMob_text.Text + "')";
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EmpInfo(EmpYear,EmpStatus,LName,FName,JobTitle,EmpPay,EmpDoB,EmpSex,EmpAddr,EmpCity,EmpState,EmpZIP,EmpCountry,EmpEAddr,EmpTelNo,EmpMobileNo) values('" + EmpYear + "', 'Active', '" + regLname_text.Text + "', '" + regFname_text.Text + "', 'NULL', '" + PayType_cb.SelectedItem.ToString() + "', '" + regDob_dtp.Value.Date + "', '" + gender + "', '" + regAddr_text.Text + "', '" + regCity_text.Text + "', '" + regState_text.Text + "', '" + regZip_text.Text + "', '" + regCountry_text.Text + "', '" + regEmail_text + "', '" + regTel_text.Text + "', '" + regMob_text.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AccountInfo(LName, FName, EmpTemplate,AccountType,EmpStatus) VALUES('" + regLname_text.Text + "','" + regFname_text.Text + "','" + template + "','" + AcctType_cb.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','Active')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Check if some column have defined length less then passed value contains

Comment: Never, never, never: concatenate inputs into SQL

Comment: I found the problem when I was looking through the code block above. I made a mistake with the insertion of the email data. Thanks though!

Comment: @MarcGravell what would you recommend as an alternative? i'm kind of new to programming with c# and sql

Comment: Use SQL parameters.

Comment: As noted by stuartd: parameters. You might want to look at tools like "dapper" (aka "dapper-dot-net") which makes it insanely easy to use parameters without having to write verbose ado.net boilerplate

Comment: For context: Google "sql injection". It is a **huge** problem, and trivially avoided. It also causes non-malicious bugs, but the security problem is more urgent.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Im looking into it now, im just having a hard time grasping it. haha i appreciate it, truly!